# ConEmu Sublime and Python to load a file in the shell

Tags: python, sublimetext3, conemu

im trying to write a sublime function that will take the current file and run it in a new shell in ConEmu, Im having some issues with escaping a \t

when I have a path that looks like

c:\ps\test.ps1

the t gets dropped, i've tried to do some things with escaping it but havent had any luck.

here is the sublime function

```
class ConemuPstestCommand(sublime_plugin.TextCommand):
   def run(self, edit):
      if self.view.file_name():
         if self.view.is_dirty():
            self.view.run_command("save")

      folder = path.dirname(self.view.file_name())
      testFile =  path.join(folder, "test.ps1")
      if(not (path.exists(testFile))):
         testFile = path.join(path.split(folder)[0],"test.ps1")
      if(path.exists(testFile)):
         testFile = testFile + "\n"

         print(testFile)
         testFile = re.sub(r'\t', r'\\t', testFile)
         #testFile = testFile.translate(str.maketrans({"\t":  r"\\\t","\\": r"\\"}))
         print(testFile)
         subprocess.call([CONEMUC, "-GUIMACRO:0","Task(""{Shells::PowerShell}"")"],startupinfo=si)
         #subprocess.call([CONEMUC, "-GUIMACRO:0","Recreate(0,0,0)"],startupinfo=si)
         subprocess.call([CONEMUC, "-GUIMACRO:0", "PASTE", "2", testFile], startupinfo=si)
```

basically the idea is that if you hit F6 in a powershell module it will run the test.ps1 in that folder. based on both of the print(testFile) the output in the sublime console looks correct, when it gets over to powershell the t on test is missing (oddly the \ is still there)

The really odd thing is if i comment out the Task() (new powershell console) line it copies it over correctly in to the current console (same conemu task type)

Im running version 150513 [64] and sublime 3 (3083)

[image: capture]

as a simple test, I ran this bit of python code from a a conemu console

```
import re,subprocess
CONEMUC = "C:\\Program Files\\ConEmu\\ConEmu\\ConEmuC64.exe"

si = subprocess.STARTUPINFO() 
si.dwFlags = subprocess.STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW
si.wShowWindow = subprocess.SW_HIDE

subprocess.call([CONEMUC, "-GUIMACRO:0","Task(""{Shells::PowerShell}"");context;print(""test"")"],startupinfo=si)
```

This will start the console fine, but it does not print the text

Also the Python version is
Python 3.4.2 (v3.4.2:ab2c023a9432, Oct  6 2014, 22:16:31) [MSC v.1600 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32

An even simpler test, I started a cmd shell and ran this command

```
ConEmuC.exe -guimacro task("{Shells::cmd}");context;print("test")
```

It will report back **OK;OK;OK**
The new shell is opened and **test** is printed in the console i ran this from. So it looks like **context** isnt really doing what it should?

I just tried another simple test

```
ConEmuC.exe -guimacro Create(0,0);context;print("test")
```

This time it worked correctly. It seems like Task() and Context dont want to work together?

It seems like 
not really sure if this is something conemu is doing or the sublime/python side of things. any thoughts?

thanks

Answer (score 2):

`Task` is asynchronous function, so you have to wait a while for new virtual console object will be created in main thread. The following command is working (checked from {cmd} tab in ConEmu).

```
conemuc -guimacro task("{cmd}"); sleep(1000); context; print("abc");
```

So, in your case it will be something like this:

```
subprocess.call([CONEMUC, "-GUIMACRO:0","Task(""{Shells::PowerShell}"");sleep(1000);context;print(""test"")"],startupinfo=si)
```

Also, here are some "guidelines":

1. Do not call `ConEmuC` twice. As described in [GuiMacro docs](http://conemu.github.io/en/GuiMacro.html) you may and actually have to execute several macros in a single `ConEmuC` call. Delimit functions by semicolon for example.
2. Same docs tells about verbatim string arguments. Only doublequotes must be doubled. Paste(2,@"Your ""string""")
3. After creating new task you have to switch execution context by `Context` function to be able to paste into newly created console.
4. At last, there are functions `PasteFile` and `Print`. They may be more suitable.

Comment: Thanks, I had tried the double quote without much luck, I'll try putting this all together. Thanks!

Comment: Not having much luck, it creates the shell ok, not really sure if Context is suppose to have a visible reaction, but its definitely not printing test to the console. here is what i did: subprocess.call([CONEMUC, "-GUIMACRO:0","Task(""{Shells::PowerShell}"");context;print(""test"")"],startupinfo=si)

Comment: ConEmu version? Screenshot?

Comment: did a whole lot of tests (updated original post) and it seems like Task() and Context dont work well together?

Comment: They do actually. Perhaps PowerShell clears input queue somewhere during starting up. Add Sleep function after context, experiment with sleep duration.

Comment: I tried it with sleep(5000) after the context with no luck. Also, i dont think its that because as i said in the updated post, a Create() intsead of a Task() works just fine.